# Applying research on the ‘signposting’ of categories in a system with a large number of different items - to a physical world environment

Tags: categorization, physical

Does any body know of  either:

1 / Any research which looks at the best ways to categorise and signpost items in a system with a large number of items ?  (This could be in a standard software interface situation)

2/ Any application of this kind of research to Physical World environments ?

Background:  I was reflecting on the ‘system’ used for signage (High Level through to Detailed) in a local supermarket: -  The apparently random choice of high level categories / combined with the random use of colour coding / random use of fonts / font sizing / label location (ie above or below the item…) etc, etc drives me nuts.

It certainly wouldn’t be how you’d do it with an online shop.

Comment: It's [designed to drive you nuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruen_transfer).

Comment: You also have a large swath of stores trying to represent a unique brand. You can't think of a mall as an online shop, you have to think of it as *many* online shops. It's still confusing, but largely a result of the physicality (thus they're all in one place) and need for a unique brand.

Comment: Googling I'm wondering whether this is covered by 'Semiotics' ? ( a subject I've never read up on)

Answer (score 1):

The field of knowledge that can answer your question is called information architecture.  While there are [some dedicated Websites](http://iainstitute.org/) around, most of this field's popular knowledge is still found in [books](http://www.google.com/search?q=information%20architecture&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).  [*Information Architecture for the World Wide Web*](http://books.google.com/books?id=2d2Ry2hZc2MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=information%20architecture&hl=en&ei=-RikTo7FDsPX0QGkorDKCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA) by [Peter Morville](http://semanticstudios.com/) and [Louis Rosenfeld](http://louisrosenfeld.com/home/) was a great place to start for me; it spends a lot of time discussing the nature of information and its organization as well as discussing the various patterns and systems people can use to find information.